# RabbitMQ rotate Single Active Consumer

Tags: rabbitmq

The RabbitMQ documentation is not clear about this (because it's probably not possible), hence my question here:

I have a large number of queues, all with Single Active Consumer enabled. Now, I have multiple instances of my consumer application running. I *hoped* that the Single Active Consumers would be rotated over my consumer applications, but unfortunately the first instance to go up is the active consumer for ALL my queues. The other instances are simply idle.

Is it somehow possible to distribute the load of all my queues with SAC enabled over all my instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately RabbitMQ doesn't seem to have something built-in to achieve this. I've solved it by passing two environment variables to each instance of my application. Say my application has 4 instances running in parallel, each instance gets the environment variables INSTANCE_CNT = 4 and INSTANCE_IDX = 0 to INSTANCE_IDX = 3.

When initialising the queues I make sure that the queues are ordered. Every instance initialises all queues if these don't exist, but only bind listeners to every queue where `queue_idx % INSTANCE_CNT == INSTANCE_IDX`. Here, queue_idx is the idx of the queue in my list of all queues. This way, instance 0 will listen to queues 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, ..., instance 1 to 1, 5, 9, 13, 15, ... etc.

Not the prettiest solution, but it works.